# SSH server won't recognize authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I've been trying to set up Git over SSH and have followed the guides I've seen to the letter. I use ssh-keygen to create a key set, log into the remote host and append the public key to .ssh/authorized_users using `cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys`. When I try to log in, I still get prompted for the user's (git user) password.

I also found a tutorial that showed how to use putty's keygen tool and followed that. Again, nothing. No variation of any tutorial I've found seems to get sshd on the remote host to allow me to log in with the generated key.

Is there any way to manually control this? I'm stuck on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4 for now.

Comment: post the output of ssh -v -v ......... (that's 2 -v's)

Comment: All else being equal, running `restorecon -R -v /root/.ssh` on the server side (not the connecting client) made a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the SSHd configuration you can check if `PubkeyAuthentication` is set to `yes` to allow public key authentication. If `PubkeyAuthentication` is set to `no` you will not be able to login with your public key and the server will prompt you for your password.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure permissions are correct:

```
$ chown <user> -R ~<user>/.ssh
$ chmod 700 ~<user>/.ssh
$ chmod 600 ~<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Also make sure that sshd_config has:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Mine are aq bit more lax than that and still work - but this is probably a better idea!

Answer (score 4):

If the user's home directory has group-write permissions, SSH will not permit public-key authentication, because otherwise any other member of the group could do the following and gain access to the user's account:

```
mv .ssh ..ssh
mkdir .ssh
cp ..ssh/* .ssh
echo "myfakekey" >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

I see group-write home directories far, FAR too often. I've gone so far as to create a cron job to "chmod g-w" every homedir once an hour when the users have refused to heed my warnings.

Comment: Great answer, that was exactly what I was playing around with :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this setting in `sshd_config`?

`PubkeyAuthentication yes`

Also check the permissions on .ssh and the private key .ssh needs to be 700 and the key 600.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the authorized_keys file - 640 should be about right. SSH can be (rightly) picky about perms on these files and the .ssh directory which should be 755 at worst.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `AuthorizedKeysFile` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  Perhaps it is specifying an alternate location.  The server's `auth.log` should tell you the reason for the authentication failure.  `root` access required.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly set the permissions on windows, use icacls.exe:

icacls.exe "C:\Users\USERNAME.ssh\authorized_keys" /inheritance:r /grant "Administrators:F" /grant "SYSTEM:F"